# Rails (5.0.1) "backwards" query in many to many self join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using the classic friendship example I am able to query for users who another user has friended like this:

```
User.first.friends
```

but is there a graceful way of grabbing the opposite relationship? Currently the query:

```
User.first.friendships
```

Returns a selection from the many to many table that looks something like this (model and schema code below):

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | friend_id |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | 2         |
| 1       | 3         |
+---------+-----------+
```

Is there an elegant way for me to grab all of the user records for people who have friended user 1? For that matter, is there a query that will get me all of the user records from user 1's friendships?

Schema.rb:

```
create_table "friendships", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "friend_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

model relations:

```
 class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "user_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :friend, foreign_key: "friend_id", class_name: "User"
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :friendships, foreign_key: "user_id", class_name: "Friendship"
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an elegant way for me to grab all of the user records for
>   people who have friended user 1?

Use `.joins` with a condition on the association:

```
User.joins(:friendships)
    .where(friendships: { friend_id: 1 })
```

> For that matter, is there a query that will get me all of the user
>   records from user 1's friendships?

```
User.joins(:friendships)
    .where(friendships: { user_id: 1 })
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I thought it would be a join but I couldn't figure it out without using a SQL string with select or join. That second query though, I think it just returns the user passed into { user: x } the amount of times it appears in the friendship table. Is there a way to query a given user for all of his/her friends?

Comment: No, it should return all users which match the condition in the where clause, so any user that at least one association that matches `WHERE friendships.user_id = 1`  will be returned

Comment: Thats not the same or even close . Thats actually equivalent to `User.joins(:friendships).where.not(User.first)`. It will give every user that does not have a friendship that belongs to `User.first`.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, should have been more thorough in testing that out. I guess the query to get the names of all friends then would be `User.joins(:friendships)
    .where(friendships: { friend_id: 1 })`